# Python 3.2.3 to log into secure website

Tags: python, html, authentication

Using python 3.2.3 I am trying to log into some websites and save the source from a hidden page to a file. I am stuck on how to log in. I have figured out how to log into a specific website but can't seem to get it working on others. The source of the webpage I am trying to log into is:

```
<form id="login_form" name="login_form" action="https://www.o2online.ie/amserver/UI/Login?org=o2ext&goto=%2F%2Fwww.o2online.ie%2Fo2%2Fmy-o2%2F" method="post">
                                    <p id="form_header">My Account login</p>
                                    <input value="Go" type="hidden" name="IDButton" id="IDButton"/>
                                    <input value="o2ext" type="hidden" name="org" id="org"/>
                                    <input value="TRUE" type="hidden" name="CONNECTFORMGET"/>
                                    <label for="IDToken1">Username</label><br />
                                    <input tabindex=1 type="text" id="IDToken1" name="IDToken1" value="Username/mobile" onclick="javascript: this.value='';" maxlength="60"  onfocus="this.value='';" tabindex=1 /><br />
                                    <br />
                                    <label for="IDToken2">Password</label><br />
                                    <input tabindex=2 type="password" id="IDToken2" name="IDToken2" value="" maxlength="30"  onfocus="this.value='';" tabindex=2 />
                                    <input tabindex=3 type="image" src="../images/my-o2/Login-button.png" id="submit_button" />
                                </form>
```

On the other pages that I have logged into sucessfully have had a submit button with a certain value but this webpage has an image for the submit button which has no value.

The code I have been using is:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import http.client
import sys

url = 'http://www.o2online.ie/o2/login/'
login_data = {
             'IDToken1': 'xxxx',
             'IDToken2': 'xxxx',
             #'submitbutton': 'submit'                           
             }

# creating an opener object that will handle the cookies
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor)

r = opener.open(url, urllib.parse.urlencode(login_data).encode())

# logged in

#Opening and saving source to a file
f = opener.open('http://www.o2online.ie/o2/my-o2/')
sys.stdout = open('file.html', 'w')
print (f.read(999999))
```

I have commented out the submit button.

Can this code be modified to log into this website?

How would you submit this form in python?